# SQS Attributes as Variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, slack

I am trying to get SQS Attributes that can become a variable I can send to Slack. The response is correct but I can't find a way to get ApproximateNumberOfMessages and ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible responses into Slack.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
logger.info("Event: " + str(event))
response = sqs.get_queue_attributes(
QueueUrl='https://queue.amazonaws.com/AccountID/Queue',
AttributeNames=['ApproximateNumberOfMessages','ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible']
)
print(response)

slack_message = {
    'channel': SLACK_CHANNEL,
    'username': "SQS Alarm",
    'attachments': [
        {
            'pretext': "%s" % (response),
            'color': "#e81e1e",
            'text': "*Messages:*\n%s" % (response),
            'mrkdown_in': ["true","pretext"]
        }
    ]    
}
```

Comment: Is your question asking how to communicate with Slack, or are you merely asking how to extract the returned attributes from `response`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned value from `get_queue_attibutes()` is:

```
{
    u'Attributes':
        {
            'ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible': '0', 
            'ApproximateNumberOfMessages': '1'
        }, 
        'ResponseMetadata': {...}
        }
}
```

Therefore, you can access the values via:

```
response['Attributes']['ApproximateNumberOfMessages']

response['Attributes']['ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible']
```

The responses seem to come back as strings.

Comment: Thanks...I added the variable in my Slack message and it provided me the proper response.



    `msgavlbe = response['Attributes']['ApproximateNumberOfMessages']
    msgflght = response['Attributes']['ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible']`